# Using Powershell script to create folder in Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

Can any one please help me letting me know the Powershell command to create a folder in Task scheduler?
I have created the script to create task in separate folder but if the folder is not there I need to create one.

Cannot find any command even after Googling a lot.

It will be great if any one can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use schtasks.exe. Maybe an answer is in this topic: [SchTasks.exe to create a task folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795560/schtasks-exe-to-create-a-task-folder)

```
schtasks /create /xml "MyTask.xml" /tn "My Task Folder\My New Task"
```

Comment: Thank you! That really helped. My situation is bit different though but really helped me giving the idea.